# Button that toggles font-weight in text area when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggleclass

I am trying to make a button that changes the font-weight to bold when it is clicked and then back to normal again when it is un-clicked. But the hard part is that I only want the part of the text area that they clicked on the bold button for to be bolded, so I do not want all of the text area to be bold. I tried making it were all of the text area would be bold at first but it won't work. I am sure it is probably really easy, but I can't figure it out. I will put my code below, thank you for your time.

```
<button class="changeButton" id="bold"><strong>Bold</strong></button>
<textarea class="textdoc" name="textdoc"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bold').click(function(){
        $('.textdoc').toggleClass('.boldClass');
    });
});
```

PS:This obviously is not all my code, comment telling me if you think I need to post all of it, but I think that the problem could just be solved with the code I have here.

Comment: *`I only want the part of the text area that they clicked on the bold button for to be bolded`* Please be more precise on this part.

Comment: Do you mean a text selection?

Comment: Your button has one word on it, how can they click differet parts of it? letters you mean?

Comment: I didn't mean it like that. I meant that I want only certain parts of the text area to be bolded

Comment: @Joshua *certain parts*? Please explain.... at random? what means "certain"?

Comment: Do you want to create wywiwyg editor? You can't do that with textarea you do this with div with contenteditable.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I mean like how in Microsoft Office Word, when you press the bold button, it only bolds the text you are typing, not the whole thing. Like if I was writing a paper and I wanted to bold just the title, I would press the bold button and then type the title. And btw thanks for your answer, I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You can't do that with textarea.

Answer (score 4):

`.toggleClass('.boldClass')` should be without the `.` like `.toggleClass('boldClass');`

Also your'e missing a closing `</textarea>` (instead of `</div>`).
Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bold').click(function(){
        $('.textdoc').toggleClass('boldClass');
    });
});
```

```css
.boldClass{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="changeButton" id="bold"><strong>Bold</strong></button>
<textarea class="textdoc" name="textdoc">TEST</textarea>
```

If you want to click on `B` and be able to write in **Bold** that you're interested in `contenteditable` attribute. (it cannot be done inside a textarea)

```js
$("[data-cmd]").click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var cmd = $(this).data().cmd;
  document.execCommand(cmd, false, null);
});
```

```css
#editable{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  min-height:100px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-cmd="bold" href="#"><b>B</b></a>
<a data-cmd="italic" href="#"><i>I</i></a>
<a data-cmd="underline" href="#"><u>U</u></a>


<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">Write here<div>
```

Comment: You can do this also with iframe with designmode.